# SSIS: Data conversion timestamp(SQL server 2008 R2) into Bytea(PostgreSQL 9.5)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis

I have table to integrate from SQL server to PostgreSQL.

In SQL Server:

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_binary_test
(
    Col timestamp
);

insert into tbl_binary_test values(default);
insert into tbl_binary_test values(default);

select * from tbl_binary_test;

Col
-----------------------
0x00000000000007D1
0x00000000000007D2
```

In PostgreSQL:

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_binary_test
(
    Col bytea
);
```

**SSIS Package Details**:

Source: OLEDB (SQL Server)

Destination: ADO NET (PostgreSQL)

Data Conversion try:

1. Byte stream - [DT_BYTES]

Output:

```
\000\000\000\000\000\000\007\321
\000\000\000\000\000\000\007\322
```

2. Unicode text stream - [DT_NTEXT]

Output:

```
00000000000007D1    
00000000000007D2
```

3. String - [DT_STR]

Output:

```
00000000000007D1
00000000000007D2
```

Question: How do I insert the same values as in SQL server in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get it right, maybe [decode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) will serve your needs:

```
tp=# select 
  decode('00000000000007D1','hex')
, pg_typeof(decode('00000000000007D1','hex'));
       decode       | pg_typeof
--------------------+-----------
 \x00000000000007d1 | bytea
(1 row)

Time: 0.680 ms
```